# Object property (type = object) is undefined despite existing in chrome console tree view

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, console, undefined

I've saved a json response as a global object variable in chrome console (chrome stored as **temp1**), set an object property of that as fieldsObj1 below:

```
>> var fieldsObj1 = temp1.fields;
```

This command in chrome console diplays a tree view of the fieldsObj1 properties, which I have expanded and pasted below, leaving the relevant 'undefined' property: **contentAll.full**.

```
>> fieldsObj1


Object {contentText.split: Array[12], metricsListed: Array[1], sourceDescription: Array[1], sourceCode: Array[1], geoLocation: Array[1]…}
    _rev: Array[1]
    coded.matchedIn: Array[3]
```

*[...many alphabetized properties skipped here]...until we get to relevant **contentAll.full** below*

```
    contentAll.full: Array[1]
        0: "Just updated my blog. Check it out! In Spite of Threats, Parents, States and Teachers are Dumping Common Core http://t.co/wlxofg2G2K  #tcot"
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array[0]
```

*[...more properties listed in chrome console object tree...]*

**contentAll.full** displays in the chrome tree object viewer as an 'Array[1]', with the array item being the text data I am trying to store to a local variable.

However, the following commands indicate the array item is inaccessible due to the containing object ,**fieldsObj1.contentAll**, being undefined.

```
fieldsObj1.contentAll.full[0]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'full' of undefined
fieldsObj1.contentAll.full
TypeError: Cannot read property 'full' of undefined
fieldsObj1.contentAll
undefined
```

**How is it undefined, when I can see it in the chrome tree view?**

How can I save that seemingly-inaccessible data to a local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fieldsObj1.contentAll.full[0]
```

is different than

```
fieldsObj1['contentAll.full'][0]
```

The sqare bracket notation allows you to define object keys more freely. As you can see, there is a property on your `fieldsObj1` called 'contentAll.full', but defining such property is not equivalent to creating `fieldsObj1.contentAll` object and defining a property `full` there.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is 'contentAll.full', a confusing naming convention and really is completely separate from another property 'contentAll.split'?

Why would the API I'm using choose to name the property like that instead of something like 'contentAllFull'? 

It seems confusing for JS to allow property names to include the period character is all. Knowing this, is there a benefit other than naming convention (albeit a confusing one) to using the . within the name of a property?